# Children with params reload page in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem about reloading the page with URL defined with param.
In `routes.js` file:

```
<Route path='/classes' component={Classes}>
    <Route path='/classes/:class_id' component={ClassDetails} />
</Route>
```

In component Classes, I wrote like this:

```
render() {
    const detailClasses = (this.props.classStore.classes && (this.props.classStore.classes.length > 0))
    ? this.props.classStore.classes.map(
          (classDetailOverview, i) => {
              return <ClassOverview classData={classDetailOverview} key={i} />}
    ): null;
    return <div className="container">
                <h2>Hello in Class Details page</h2>
                <Box className="OgeClassesPage">
                    {this.props.children ? this.props.children : detailClasses}
                </Box>
           </div>;
}
```

And in `ClassOverview` component, I import a Link of `react-router` for link it into `ClassDetails` component.

```
 render () {
    const classUrl = 'classes/' + this.state.classOverview.class_id
    return <Box className='OgeClassBox' alignContent='center' align='center'>
      <a href={classUrl}><h3>
        {this.state.classOverview.class_title}
      </h3>
      </a>
    <img className='OgeClassImage' src={this.state.class_image} />
    <div className='OgeClassDesc padding-10'>
      {this.state.classOverview.class_description.slice(0, 100)}
    </div>
  </Box>
}
```

But when I click a link to access class details, it reloads a page. I don't  understand about this, it shouldn't reload a page.

Have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Can you add the code from your ClassOverview component? It is likely some issue with how you are using Link, as that's what should be intercepting the click and running it through the router, instead of through the browser.

Comment: Yes, of course. I will edit above post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to link to another URL within the router, you'll have to use the [`<Link>` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link). This component will intercept clicks headed to the browser and send it to the router instead. It is interchangeable with a standard `<a>`, with the exception of taking a `to` prop.

```
<Link to={classUrl}>
  <h3>
    {this.state.classOverview.class_title}
  </h3>
</Link>
```